# Select only classes with best metric (f1 score) in a multiclass classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass classification problem with almost 50 classes. After I ran the models some of the classes get ver good scores (.70 and higher) and others perform badly.

What I want to do, is based on the metrics I obtain, **keep only classes with good results and create a model only for them**.

How can I pick the good classes out of the result of the classification report of my model?

This are the classes I want to extract and keep

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`classification_report` has an `output_dict` parameter that causes the function to return a dictionary instead of a string.

If you have a threshold (e.g. `0.7`) for *good* f1-scores, you can iterate over the results and select the labels with values higher than the threshold:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
y_pred = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3]

cr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)

for l in labels:
    if (f1_score := cr[str(l)]["f1-score"]) > 0.7:
        print(f"Label {l}, f1-score: {f1_score:.3f}")
```

Output:

```
Label 0, f1-score: 0.750
Label 2, f1-score: 0.800
```